# Next.js: How to get the URL paramters

Tags: reactjs, url, next.js, query-string

I am trying to get URL paramters in a NextJS component:
http://...../page?id=1

I tried this:

```
export default function Page() {
    const route = useRouter()
    const params = route.params
    const id = params.get('id')
```

but unfortunately, 'params' is always empty.
Does anyone know why or a different way of how to get the 'id' parameter

Comment: And how you got to the URI? Did you change URI with any API?

Comment: do not use params, use "query":  router.query

Comment: Which parameters are you trying to get? There are path parameters and there are query parameters. Based on `"http://...../page?id=1"` it appears to be the latter. Use [`router.query`](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next/router#router-object).